# SQL Server 2012: NUMA node shown as offline without special affinity settings

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, memory

My main production server has four NUMA nodes with two SQL Server 2012 instances on it.  One of the instances has the CPU affinity set to use only one NUMA node, and sys.dm_os_nodes reflects that correctly. The other instance has no affinity settings, so it should show all 4 NUMA nodes as online, I would think, but it shows Node 3 as offline, which happens to be the node that's online for the other instance. Is there a bug in SQL Server 11.0.3128?

Comment: Interesting. Maybe with the licencing revamp they locked things down to the number of CPUs in Windows so you can only use each one in one instance. What happens if you shut down the instance assigned one NUMA node, and then start up or restart the other instance? Does it still use 3, or does it now use 4?

Comment: What edition of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @Jon: this is a 24x7 prod server so I can't test that for a couple weeks.

Comment: @Sean: Enterprise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer:
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sql_shep/sql-server-2012-license-core-limitaion)

My consultants installed the wrong version (CAL instead of core), so it's limited to 20 cores.